# R DBI bind variable performance

Tags: r, postgresql, sqlite, dbi

I am facing performance issues when using bind variables with DBI package. My original use case is with Postgres database, but for reproducibility, below I use in-memory SQLite that has exactly the same issue - when I select data from some table by id (in Postgres the column is indexed) the parametrized version runs multiple times longer on selecting number of rows than SQL with IDs pasted in `IN` statement:

```
library(DBI)
library(tictoc)

sample.data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100000,
  value = rnorm(100000)
)

sqlite <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(
  sqlite, "sample_data",
  sample.data,
  overwrite = T
)

tic("Load by bind")
ids <- 50000:50100
res <- dbSendQuery(sqlite, "SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE id = $1")
dbBind(res, list(ids))
result <- dbFetch(res)
dbClearResult(res)
toc()

# Load by bind: 0.81 sec elapsed

tic("Load by paste")
ids <- 50000:50100
result2 <- dbGetQuery(sqlite, paste0("SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE id IN (", paste(ids, collapse = ","), ")"))
toc()

# Load by paste: 0.04 sec elapsed
```

Seems that I should have some obvious mistake as prepared queries are supposed to be faster (and I do see it with Python/SQLAlchemy on the same Postgres example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query `... id = $1` is executed 101 times; your second query `... id in (..)` is executed once. If you audit on the DBMS side (not demonstrating that here), then you'd see 101 individual queries.

Up front, a common mistake is to simplify modify your statement to use an `IN (?)` clause,

```r
dbGetQuery(pgcon, "SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE id in (?)", params = list(ids))
```

but this also executes the query 101 times, feeling the same performance woes of `result1`.

To use parameter binding with the much more efficient `IN (..)` clause, you need to provide that many question-marks (or dollar-numbers).

```r
bench::mark(
  result1 = dbGetQuery(sqlite, "SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE id = $1", params = list(ids)),
  result2 = dbGetQuery(sqlite, paste0("SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE id IN (", idcommas, ")")),
  result3 = dbGetQuery(sqlite, paste0("SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE id IN (", qmarks, ")"),
                       params = as.list(ids)),
  min_iterations = 50
)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result             memory                  time          gc               
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>             <list>                  <list>        <list>           
# 1 result1    280.97ms  347.4ms      2.86    20.6KB        0    50     0      17.5s <df[,2] [101 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [14 x 3]> <bch:tm [50]> <tibble [50 x 3]>
# 2 result2      7.31ms   8.21ms    115.      15.6KB        0    58     0    502.2ms <df[,2] [101 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [12 x 3]> <bch:tm [58]> <tibble [58 x 3]>
# 3 result3      7.57ms   8.93ms    113.      28.4KB        0    57     0      506ms <df[,2] [101 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [28 x 3]> <bch:tm [57]> <tibble [57 x 3]>
```

If you're curious, it performs the same (*significantly* faster) on a postgres instance (though I changed your `$1` to `?`: sqlite accepts both, odbc/postgres only supports qmarks):

```r
pgcon <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ...) # local docker postgres instance
bench::mark(...)
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result             memory                  time          gc               
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>             <list>                  <list>        <list>           
# 1 result1     967.4ms    1.05s     0.933    20.6KB        0    50     0     53.57s <df[,2] [101 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [14 x 3]> <bch:tm [50]> <tibble [50 x 3]>
# 2 result2        57ms   67.7ms    14.4      18.1KB        0    50     0      3.47s <df[,2] [101 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [13 x 3]> <bch:tm [50]> <tibble [50 x 3]>
# 3 result3      56.9ms  65.17ms    14.3      21.4KB        0    50     0       3.5s <df[,2] [101 x 2]> <Rprofmem[,3] [15 x 3]> <bch:tm [50]> <tibble [50 x 3]>
```

I also tested on odbc/sql-server with very similar results.

`result2` and `result3` are generally quite close here on all three DBMSes, and in fact on different samplings the former is faster than the latter, so I'll call their performance comparison a wash. What, then, is the motivation for using binding? In many cases, it's mainly an academic discussion: most of the time, you're doing nothing wrong by not using it (and instead using your `paste(ids, collapse=",")` method).

However:

- *Inadvertent* "sql injection". Technically SQL injection must be malevolent to be labeled as such, but I informally attribute "oops" moments in SQL queries where the data has embedded quotes, and by pasting it into a static query string, I broke the quoting. Fortunately for me, all it did was break the parsing of the query, I have not [deleted this year's student records](https://xkcd.com/327/).

  A common mistake is to try to use `sQuote` to escape embedded quotes. Long-story-short: nope, SQL does it differently. Many SQL users do not know that to escape an embedded single quote, one must double it:

  ```r
  sQuote("he's Irish")
  # [1] "'he's Irish'"                      # WRONG

  DBI::dbQuoteString(sqlite, "he's Irish")
  # <SQL> 'he''s Irish'                     # RIGHT for both sqlite and pgcon
  ```
- Query optimization. Most (all? I don't know for certain) DBMSes do some form of query optimization, attempting to take advantage of an index and/or similar measures. To be good at it, this optimization is done once for query and then cached. However, if you change even one letter of the query, you risk a cache-miss (I am not saying "always" because I have not audited the caching code ... but the premise is clear, I think). This means that changing a query from `select * from mytable where a=1` to `... a=2` does *not* get a cache-hit, and it is optimized (again).

  Contrast that with `select * from mytable where a=?` with parameter-binding, and you benefit from the caching.

  Note that if your list of `ids` changes length, then the query is likely to be re-optimized (changes from `id in (?,?)` to `id in (?,?,?)`); I don't if that is truly a cache miss, again not having audited the DBMSes code.

BTW: your mention of *"prepared statement"* is very much aligned with this query optimization, but the performance penalty you are experiencing is much more about running the same query 101 times than anything to do with cache hits/misses.

Comment: Thank You for the comprehensive answer! Pasting question marks in parameters still does not seems like a good choice. Probably You have a clue how to bind parameters for query that requires Postgres array like this one:
`SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE id = ANY(?)`

Comment: I'm using the odbc driver for this, and pasting question marks is the only option for ODBC connections. The premise is the same, though, if you'd prefer to use dollar-numbers: `paste(paste0("$", seq_along(ids)), collapse=",")` should work.

Comment: While `ANY` is supported by different DBMSes, it is not identical: postgres supports `"select * from sample_data where id = any(array[1,2,3])"`, but that type of syntax is not supported in non-postgres; SQL Server's `ANY` is quite a bit different, not supporting that mechanism at all. Since you started with postgres and sqlite as your databases of demonstration, your suggestion of `ANY(.)` is out of scope. (Further, `?` is standard for ODBC, as I said, so calling it "not a good choice" seems premature. I would prefer ODBC supports named bindings, but it is not the case, we're stuck with `?`.)

Comment: I'm looking to Postgres' `ANY(.)` because this would allow to re-use a single prepared statement for an arbitrary number of parameters without re-generating the query with appropriate number of `?`, anyhow I understand it's already a different story.